# Check if number is on string using strpos

Tags: php

Hi guys i m confuse with this situation

```
if(strpos($_SESSION["varPermissions"],'3') === false) {// was using == false now ===

echo "THERE IS NOT NUMBER 3"; } else { echo "THERE IS A NUMBER 3";}
```

My session returns  |0|2|12|10|8|7|13|14|15|27|20|25|26|21|29|

so the number 3 is not on the session but i still get THERE IS A NUMBER 3

example if i looking for 28 i get answer correctly

this happen on online server running php 5.4  on xampp localhost running php 5.5 works fine

Comment: I thinks its becuz the number 13 is on session, do i m right?

Comment: There are many ways to fix this, but the million dollar question is: why is `$_SESSION["varPermissions"]` a string and not an array?

Comment: There is 3 in the sesstion string

Comment: Add the pipe `if(strpos($_SESSION["varPermissions"],'|3|') === false) {// was using == false now ===

echo "THERE IS NOT NUMBER 3"; } else { echo "THERE IS A NUMBER 3";}`

Comment: Do you mean exactly number 3 not 13 or 23 or 33?

Comment: Hi @Jon when the use log in the system get hes permissions on database and each page have a id, if the page id r on string the page shows fine, if not shows a message, its a old website i m just try to fix.

Answer (score 0):

it finds 3 because there is a 3 in 13.

```
$ex = explode('|', $_SESSION["varPermissions"]);
if(in_array('3', $ex))
{
    echo "Found 3";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to search for exact phrase in the string

```
$values = explode('|', $_SESSION['varPermissions']);
if (in_array('3', $values)) {
   echo 'Number 3 exists.';
}
else {
   echo 'There is no number 3';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (in case when $_SESSION["varPermissions"] is a string)

```
if (in_array('3', explode ('|',$_SESSION["varPermissions"]))) {
    echo "THERE IS NOT NUMBER 3"; 
} else {
    echo "THERE IS A NUMBER 3";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fixing this problem in maintenance mode and want to make the least amount of changes, simply search for the delimiters along with your value:

```
if (strpos($_SESSION['varPermissions'], "|3|) === false) {
    echo "Not found";
}
```

The proper solution, however, would be to make `$_SESSION['varPermissions']` an array in the first place; this would allow you to simply write

```
if (!in_array(3, $_SESSION['varPermissions'])) {
    echo "Not found";
}
```

Personally I don't see any benefit for splitting the string into an array on the spot if you are not going to fix it all the way to the beginning.